# Convert js function to jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following javascript function which I would like to convert to Jquery instead:

```
function confirm() {

    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "index.php?tag=' . $dt . '";
    var params = "confirm_ref=' . urlencode(encrypt($br,$k)) . '";
    http.open("POST", url, true);
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {

            }
                }
    http.send(params);
    }
```

Any pointers on how to set it up properly?
Thanks.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: ... I mean, just looking at the`$.post` or `$.ajax` docs should be sufficient.

Comment: `$.post(url, { data : params}).done(function() { ... });`

Comment: You can also refer for function / Plugin https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

Comment: @Aman Why? Nothing here requires anything beyond what's already provided by jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery has a ready to use library to send Ajax Request.

Here's a working sample - https://www.formget.com/submit-form-using-ajax-php-and-jquery/

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259